# Существует ли союз "значит" и какой это союз?

Tags: грамматика, союзы

Из словаря:

ЗНАЧИТ, союз. Таким образом, следовательно. *Тучи собираются, значит будет дождь. Ты сердишься, значит ты не прав.*

Если ***значит*** ― это союз, то какой он, сочинительный или подчинительный? И предложение тоже какое (БСП, ССП, СПП)?

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Аналогично, согласно словарю,  наречие *поэтому* может быть союзным словом, а вводное слово *следовательно* ― союзом.

В то же время в грамматике ясно сказано, что в СПП с придаточным следствия используется только союз ТАК ЧТО.

Вот и интересно, почему, к примеру, не считать "поэтому" союзом со значением следствия в СПП, аналогичным союзу "так что". Может быть, есть причины, не позволяющие это сделать?

Но называть ***значит, следовательно, поэтому*** просто союзами ― это значит вносить путаницу в анализ грамматических конструкций.

Comment: Встречные вопросы: *следовательно* тоже может быть союзом, какой это союз? *Поэтому* - союзное слово, какая связь , какие предложения? По-моему, должен быть один ответ для всех таких союзов/союзных слов.